# Unable to find root cause why i am unable to program the LPC54606 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, keil, nxp-microcontroller, lpc, segger-jlink

LPC54606 Unable to Connect to Target

I am using LPC54606J512BD100 microcontroller and facing a very serious issue.

The issue is that after successful programming and working with it the microcontroller at random stops getting programmed and giving error unable to connect to core.

[image: Error Device not found(https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9YWD.png)]

[image: Error Flash download(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgWCb.png)]

[image: Keil Output window]

**Regarding Programming board:**

Using LPC-Link 2 Rev B (https://www.nxp.com/design/software/development-software/mcuxpresso-software-and-tools-/lpc-link2:OM13054) debug board for programming.

Tried in CMSIS-DAP and J-Link (SW) mode.

**Board Connection:**

- JP1 - Closed
- JP2 - Open
- Using J6 Connector (1 - V_REF, 2 - SWDIO, 3 - SWCLK, 6 - RESET, 8 - GND)

**Regarding Controller LPC54606J512BD100:**

PIO0_2 to PIO0_6 are left unconnected.

**Regarding IDE:**

I am using Keil uVision5.

I need help as I am unable to program the microcontroller. Please let me know if any further detail is required if any.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution
Implementations:

1. Both JP1 and JP2 to be closed
2. SWDIO, SWCLK to be pulled up by 10K to V_REF
3. Power supply if given from source or programmer board works.

Also, if the connector pins while connecting misaligns and for a fraction of seconds touch the wrong pins destroys the controller. So, Connection only when both programmer and controller are powered off.

Hope this will help someone facing similar kind of issue.